# Split big array in X parts using jq

Tags: jq

I would like use `jq` for divide a large array into 6 parts. For this, i think use `_nwise()` methode, but the result is wrong :

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V00Ki.png)

I'm not really understand why `[_nwise(length / 6)]` return 7 parts ??

Comment: Basic maths: 211 / 6 is 35.166, this gets rounded down to 35, and 211 is 6 * 35 + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words:

```
 [_nwise(length / 6 | ceil)]
```

If a large array cannot be assumed, you can pad with []:

```
[_nwise(length / 6|ceil) ]+[range(0;6-length)|[]]
```